# soap xml response - how to get that stubborn data out

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I'm trying to get the contents of the `faultstring` element and I'm more comfortable with SimpleXML's object syntax (`$xml->...->faultstring`.) The DomDocument method below works, but I'd prefer to stick with SimpleXML.

PHP version 5.6.40, Libxml 2.9.1.

```
$xmlResponse = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <soap:Fault>
                <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
                <faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: https://gw1.domain.com:4430/.</faultstring>
                <detail />
            </soap:Fault>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>';

// DOES NOT WORK
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlResponse,NULL,NULL,"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$faultstring = (string) ($xml->Body->Fault->faultstring);
var_dump($faultstring);

// WORKS
$_DomObject = new DOMDocument;
$_DomObject->loadXML($xmlResponse);
if (!$_DomObject) die("Error while parsing the document");
$s = simplexml_import_dom($_DomObject);
foreach(['faultcode','faultstring','detail'] as $tag) {
    echo $tag.' => '.$_DomObject->getElementsByTagName($tag)[0]->textContent.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$xmlResponse = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: https://gw1.domain.com:4430/.</faultstring>
            <detail />
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
XML;
```

XML namespaces are getting in the way; they're the `soap:` prefix on the element names. It's possible to register all the namespaces and get it working that way, but just using XPath is easier:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlResponse);
$fault = $xml->xpath("//faultstring");
echo (string)$fault[0] . "\n";
```

---

And here's how it looks using namespaces. You still get the object syntax, but it becomes a lot more complicated.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlResponse);
$fault = $xml->children("soap", true)->Body->children("soap", true)->Fault->children()->faultstring;
echo (string)$fault . "\n";
```

---

Output for both:

```
Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: https://gw1.domain.com:4430/.
```

Comment: Silly me, I thought the “children” part was implicit! I actually tried that, but did not take it far enough. Excellent solution.

Comment: Calling `$xml->getNamespaces(true)` is unnecessary here (and casting to object is just weird, IMO). If you want to rely on the document-specific prefix not changing, just use `->children('soap', true)`, but better is to rely on the namespace URI, e.g. `define('XMLNS_SOAP', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')` and then `->children(XMLNS_SOAP)`.

Comment: @IMSoP The cast to object is just to avoid the array notation but yes a string would be better. Been a long time since I worked with SimpleXML instead of DomDocument so I’m not super familiar with it.

Comment: @TomTerrific the explicit call to `children()` is only needed because of the namespaces. Otherwise yes it’s implied.

Comment: @miken32 I've never understood why people want to "avoid the array notation" - I'd happily see `stdClass` scrubbed from the language - but you're not alone. The more important point is a) there's a built-in shortcut for referencing namespace by alias, and b) referencing by alias *can break any time your source changes its encoding slightly*, whereas referencing by URI will break only if the underlying data changes.

Comment: @miken32 in your xpath solution, why is registerXPathNamespace('soap') not used? Without it, the namespace prefix is ignored, right?

Comment: @TomTerrific XPath doesn't seem to care about namespaces. I'm no expert on this stuff so I don't know why, but XPath can search for namespaced elements just with a query like `//soap:Fault`

Comment: @miken32 The double-slash is the reason - it's a global search prefix. A single-slash indicates an absolute path, and in that case the 'soap:' prefixes would be needed. The key (for me anyway) was realizing that xpath is not just a name, it's a thing with a syntax. The php manual for the xpath method mentions it briefly, but provides no syntax or link thereto. Found it on w3schools.

Comment: @TomTerrific Yes I know that, what I meant was that most XML libraries won't let you specify the namespace in plain text, as though it were part of the element's name. E.g. `DomDocument::getElementsByTagName("soap:Fault")` won't return any elements.